# Hot module reloading on server side with loopback

Tags: webpack, server-side, loopback, hot-module-replacement

I'm using webpack and I'm trying to implement HMR with loopback to reload the server side.

So that every time I change a json configuration file (for example), loopback is updated.

I cannot figure out how to to this with module.hot
I also had the idea to use chokidar to watch for file changes but I have no clue how I can reload modules or reboot loopback.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

HMR has a function called 'accept'. There you can put your called and do whatever you want when you detected a refresh from HMR.

Unfortunately the current documentation lacks of information, but you can have a look to the [old one](https://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement.html#accept)

In case you want to kick in your loopback, you could do it like this

```
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('path/to/a/specific/dependency', (updatedDependency) => {
     // loopback(updatedDependency)
   })
}
```

Comment: I see, but how can I get module.hot to be injected into my server code?
Right now, it is injected into the client side because I use a webpack.config.client.js file which is processed by webpack-dev-middleware and webpack-hot-middleware on my server code.
I tried to follow the steps from here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/hmr-react/
But these steps are clearly for enabling HMR on the client and not on the server.